# Div hover that shows another div

Tags: html, css

I have the code below and I can't make it like so: when I hover .iconanim the imageshdrq to appear. I tried different things but couldn't make it done. Can someone guide me to the result that I want ? I tough that adjusting the height of .imageshdr will make it work but still no results.

```css
.iconanim:hover + .imageshdr{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.test{
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.test2{
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/UZhKDMu.png');
    border: 0;
   padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
  outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s ease; 
}

.test3{
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
  outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s ease; 
}


.imageshdr{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    height: 100px;
    right: 3%;
    bottom: 24%;
}

.imageshdr:hover{
     opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageshdr"><button class="test"></button>
 <button class="test2"></button>
 <button class="test3"></button></div>
<div class="headerchanger"><div class="iconanim">Test</div>
```

Comment: '+' will target the first element that is placed immediately after it and not a previous element.

Comment: <div class="headerchanger"><div class="iconanim">Test</div>
<div class="imageshdr"><button class="test"></button>
 <button class="test2"></button>
 <button class="test3"></button></div>